# How work RetryTopic with other groupId and backOff properties

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, consumer

I'm using spring-kafka and *@RetryTopic* and I can't understand how this works

1. for different groupId-s :

   For example, the topic ***TestTopic*** contains 5 messages and is
   listened to by 2 consumers - ***groupId_1*** and ***groupId_2***

   ***groupId_1*** did not process message #2 and sent it to ***TestTopic_1***

   ***groupId_2*** did not process message #4 and sent it to ***TestTopic_1***

   When ***groupId_1*** and ***groupId_2*** read messages from
   ***TestTopic_1***, it turns out that ***groupId_1*** subtracts both messages #2 and #4 (is it obtained again?) And ***groupId_1***
   subtracts message #2 (is it repeated?) and #4 How it works? How to
   avoid re-processing?
2. And a question about setting up work ***@RetryTopic*** about
   backoff, for example I have a setting

   ```
   @RetryableTopic(
            attempts = "3",
            topicSuffixingStrategy = TopicSuffixingStrategy.SUFFIX_WITH_INDEX_VALUE,
            backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000, maxDelay = 5_000, random = true),
            dltTopicSuffix = "dead-two"
   )
   ```

   Do I understand correctly that the thread reading from the partition
   is blocked for a delay time, after which it sends a message to the
   topic for re-reading or is a separate thread created for this
   waiting and sending?
3. And during this delay the application crashes, then the message will
   not be sent to the topic ***TestTopic_N***?
4. And why is maxDelay needed if delay and attempts are specified??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is not designed to handle that situation; each consumer group is independent; you would work around it by using custom retry topic naming so that the retry topics include the group id; that is not the case by default. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#topic-naming

Also see Also see this section in the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#multi-retry You can simply set different `retryTopicSuffix` and `dltTopicSuffix` on each listener.

2. The thread is not blocked; the record is immediately written to the next retry topic; the consumer on that topic (when it receives the record) looks at the timestamp and, if it is too early, rejects the message, the partition is paused on that consumer until the time expires, and then it is resumed and the record is redelivered.
3. See #2.
4. `maxDelay` is only used when using an exponential back off (with a multiplier). e.g. `delay = 2, multiplier = 2.0, maxDelay = 10` would result in `2, 4, 8, 10, 10...` up to max attempts.

**EDIT**

Further to comments below; here is an example of using existing topics for the retry topics:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class So77216081Application extends RetryTopicConfigurationSupport {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So77216081Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected RetryTopicComponentFactory createComponentFactory() {
        return new RetryTopicComponentFactory() {

            @Override
            public RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory retryTopicNamesProviderFactory() {
                return new MyNamesProvider();
            }

        };
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<String, String> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so77216081", "foo");
        };
    }

}

@Component
class Listener {

    @KafkaListener(id = "so77216081", topics = "so77216081")
    @RetryableTopic(attempts = "3", autoCreateTopics = "false")
    void listen(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC)
    String topic) {
        System.out.println(in + " from " + topic);
        throw new RuntimeException("test");
    }

    @DltHandler
    void dlt(String in, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_TOPIC)
    String topic) {
        System.out.println(in + " from " + topic);
    }

}

class MyNamesProvider implements RetryTopicNamesProviderFactory {

    @Override
    public RetryTopicNamesProvider createRetryTopicNamesProvider(Properties properties) {
        return new SuffixingRetryTopicNamesProvider(properties) {

            @Override
            public String getTopicName(String topic) {
                if (properties.isMainEndpoint() || properties.isDltTopic()) {
                    return super.getTopicName(topic);
                }
                else if (super.getTopicName(topic).endsWith("-0")) {
                    return "TestFirstrandomtopic";
                }
                else if (super.getTopicName(topic).endsWith("-1")) {
                    return "TestSecondrandomtopic";
                }
                else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Shouldn't get here - attempts is only 3");
                }
            }

        };
    }

}
```

```
foo from so77216081
foo from TestFirstrandomtopic
foo from TestSecondrandomtopic
foo from so77216081-dlt
```

Note that since `autoCreateTopics` is false, all 4 topics must have previously been added to the brokers.

Comment: I'm understood, thank you; Another question arose - can I first create Topics and later use them as Topics for retry? Should I indicate to RetrayTopics that I need to send messages to my pre-created topics, and not create them dynamically?

Comment: Yes, set `autoCreateTopics` to `false` on the annotation.

Comment: I mean, if I previously created topics with random names, for example ***TestFirstrandomtopic*** and ***TestSecondrandomtopic***, how can I say ***@RetryTopic*** use them as toppics for the first retry and the second retry for ***TestTopic***?

Comment: See the link in my answer for how to use custom topic names; specifically, this subsection: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#custom-naming-strategies Also search here; I have answered several questions with examples.

Comment: Tnx, I try it; But there you can determine the name only for the topics of the first re -attempt? Is it possible to indicate the name of the topic that will be supposed to be used by the second and third attempts?

Comment: See the edit to my answer for an example.

Comment: it's work, tnx you for your answer